# Send email with Twisted on Python3

Tags: python-3.x, twisted

I see several examples [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/mail/examples/index.html#auto0) about sending email with Twisted. However, I've read that **twisted-mail** isn't going to be ported on Python 3.
Has Twisted got any alternative in Python3 or manipulation with e-mail is away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Plan/Python3), there is a plan to bring `twisted` into Python 3 with full functionality.

However, there are also some other e-mail modules available in Python 3.

- [This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_sending_email.htm) is a 
  tutorial which uses `smtplib`, a module which uses the [SMTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol).
- There is also an `email` module built in to Python 3, as detailed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) in the docs.